# Best way to display only distinct value from multiple div tags with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can i display only **distinct** value from multiple div tags with same class name

```
<div class="categories">cat 1</div>
<div class="categories">cat 1</div>
<div class="categories">cat 2</div>
<div class="categories">cat 2</div>
<div class="categories">cat 2</div>
<div class="categories">cat 3</div>
<div class="categories">cat 3</div>
```

I would like to display only distinct value and hide the rest

- cat 1
- cat 2
- cat 3

Comment: Use jquery.each(".categories", function(){ 'record uniques here' });

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! [Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: You want to retrieve the unique values (into an array) or you want to show only one of each repeated text value?

Comment: This is definitely something that should be handled on the server-side rather than client-side. You should re-formulate the query which pulls the data from the database.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus why? what if the OP is calling a service (API, REST, WebService, etc) and has no control on what gets returned but wants to filter by unique values?  why make the assumption the OP has control of the data set s/he is given to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably somthing like this?

```
  $('.categories').filter(function(){ //use filter on all .categories
       var txt = $.trim(this.innerHTML); //Get the text of current
       return ($(this).nextAll().filter(function () { //filter all of the proceeding siblings which has the same text
            return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === txt
        }).length); //send true or false (in fact truthy or falsy to ask to hide the current element in question)
   }).hide();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gZgHy/)**

Another derivative and this will hide the first ones while the prev ones will hide the last one.

```
$(function () {
    $('.categories').each(function(){
       var txt = $.trim(this.innerHTML);
       $(this).nextAll(':visible').filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === txt
        }).hide();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqrn5/)**

Another approach which takes less iteration and creates a selector with indexes of the elements to be hidden.

```
$(function () {
    var arrText = [];
    $(($('.categories').map(function(){
       var txt = $.trim(this.innerHTML);
        if(arrText.indexOf(txt) == -1) 
            arrText.push(txt);
        else 
           return('.categories:eq(' + $('.categories').index(this) + ')'); //create the selector with eq
    }).get().join(','))).hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dYeYY/)**

Comment: If there is other div tags.  How do you ignore them?

    <div class="categories">cat 1</div>
    <div class="categories">cat 1</div>
    <div class="foo">foo 1</div>
    <div class="categories">cat 2</div>
    <div class="foo">foo 2</div>
    <div class="categories">cat 2</div>
    <div class="categories">cat 2</div>
    <div class="categories">cat 3</div>
    <div class="categories">cat 3</div>

Comment: @user2769820 try replace your htmls in the fiddles i provided in my answer and see if there is any issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$(function () {
    var text = []
    $('.categories').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).text(), text)<0) {
            text.push($(this).text())
        }
    });
    // you can use now the variable "text"
    console.log(text);
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7My2C/1/)

Comment: Seems to be the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.categories').each(function() {
    var textContent = $(this).text();
    if ($('.categories:visible').not(this).filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == textContent;
    }).length) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cYjyn/1/

**EDIT: changed :contains in favour of .filter to avoid submatches**